# Change field value with javascript on submit

Tags: php, tinymce, crud, atk4

I need to execute something like this in a CRUD form (simplified example):

```
$crud->form->js('submit',$crud->form->getElement('data')->js()->val('My text'));
```

I need to change `data` field before submit. The event is executed but field is not updated. I guess POST values are already assigned when this event is fired.

`data` is a textarea hidden by a TinyMCE component I'm trying to integrate as an addon. All works ok but when form is sent via ajax you need to manually update textarea from TinyMCE content. I've tested a lot of ways, including "raw" javascript `(js("submit","document.getElementById(...)")` but no luck until now.

Do you know how can I have this field changed before submitting?.

Thanks!!

Comment: tricky question :) some ideas before there is a proper answer:

destroy the button then create new one which performs JS action then submits+Disable enter on the form (here is how: http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/form/enhancing).  Another idea is to assign submit() event on form, not the div. ->js(true)->find('form')->submit( ... ); Finally we can patch form.js, submitForm method with a callback (beforeSubmit)

Comment: Thanks Romans! Finally I decided to modify ui.atk4_form.js adding just one line that launches the event 'beforesubmit'. I sent a pull request to github if you want to include it in the project. As atk4_form uses preventDefault stoppropagation you cant't simply bind event submit to form and then the other solutions are too complicated for something so simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved adding `this.form.trigger('beforesubmit')` in `ui.atk4-form.js` before form data serialization.

Then you can add in your code:

```
$form->js('beforesubmit', ...
  //Changes to fields done here are submitted because form fields are still not processed.
)
```